# iOS9: Will App Thinning work on older iOS version before iOS9?

Tags: ios, ios9, app-thinning

Apple brings `App Thinning` with iOS 9, by theory, the thinning process is done on apple's server, I understand it as apple compiles my App from `bitcode` to machine code.

So if I submit an App built with iOS 9 SDK, will Apple also slice my package for older version iOS systems like iOS 7 and iOS 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [App thinning Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html):

> Note: For iOS apps, sliced apps are supported on the latest iTunes and on devices running iOS 9.0 and later; otherwise, the App Store delivers universal apps to customers.

So devices with iOS 7 and iOS 8 installed will receive the universal version.

Comment: Thank you, would you mind showing me the link to this doc?

Comment: `Sliced apps are supported on devices running 9.0 and later; otherwise, the store delivers universal apps to customers.` is only listed under the "Slicing" section. Are you sure that this includes Bitcode?

Answer (score 0):

so I suppose that could mean that the Universal app could now be quite huge, since it's going to have many different slices.  Me myself - I'm going to have at least three slices for iPad, 6" and iPods.  But in the same token - most users should be upgraded to iOS 9 in a few months.  Apple's conversion rate is very fast these days.